# symfony3 - Clearing session after rendering a view

Tags: symfony

I have a simple question , it is :

Does symfony3 really clears session after rendering a view ?

PS : im getting all the data in the rendered view from session , so if it does really clear the session i will get an empty twig or an error after reloading the page , but i dont get that .

here is my code , how do i clear session after rendering a view please :

```
    return $this->render('@Boubou/my_twig.html.twig', [
                'var1' => $var1,
                'var2' => $var2
            ]);
    $session->clear();
```

Comment: Nothing gets executed after the `return`. You will need to call another request to clear the session. In the `twig`, add a `document.ready` block and call a controller via ajax to clear the session. There are other alternatives too.

Comment: What are these alternatives ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not clear the session before calling the render?

This is the approach,

Get the session data and assign to variables/ arrays (or however you like) before calling the render.

```
$var1 = $session->get('var1');
$var2 = $session->get('var2');
```

Then, clear the session.

```
$session->clear();
```

Finally, pass those values to the render (as you are already doing).

```
return $this->render('@Boubou/my_twig.html.twig', [
         'var1' => $var1,
         'var2' => $var2
]);
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much , made my day , keep it up :D

Comment: No problem @DhiaEddineAyadi. My pleasure :)